# Template for loop if the current iteration is different from the previous iteration

Tags: html, django, templates

I want to have

```
{% for user_id, x, y in information %}
    {% if it is the first time that user_id is different from the previous iteration %}
        do something
    {% elseif user_id is different from the user_id in the previous iteration %}
        do something
    {% endif %}
```

Can anyone help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `{% ifchanged %}`. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

Comment: What about it is the first time the user_id changes